# wcfsvchost process still running after exit

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a client application, which interacts with a server, which is an WCF-service. And I have a problem: I launch my service via comand-line using such a command:

`start WcfSvcHost.exe /service:SodisWebServer.dll /config:SodisWebServer.dll.config`

and in tray i have an icon of WCFSvcHost.exe. When i press the Exit button on it I expect my server to shut down, but when i try to relaunch it, i catch an `AddressAlreadyInUseException` because there is a listener on service ip+port and after I pressed Exit on WCFSvcHost.exe the process is still running.

I'll be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If the process is not closed it might be waiting for channel closure because of an exception being thrown, etc.

Another typical cause is that if you created the WCF service  through a "Service Library" project type the Visual Studio IDE will use an internal WCFSVCHost tool for testing service library. If the VS is running then another instance of WCFSVCHost might be running even though you closed the one that you started manually (but then you would receive it after the first attempt to run the host).

Just in case I suggest you uncheck the box labeled "*Start WCF Service Host when debugging another project in the same solution*" in the project properties or try building a console application to host the WCF service for test (self-hosting WCF service).